Ensuring geometries read from shapefile contain only Coodinate objects instead of CoordinateXYZM using Java GeoTools
I recently upgraded GeoTools library from version 22.1 to 31.1.
Since upgrading, I'm getting lots of exceptions "Invalid ordinate index: 3" during my program execution.
After some investigation, I believe I have discovered the cause:

GeoTools 31.1 now supports reading Shapefiles with XYZM geometries.
It appears to always return geometries containing CoordinateXYZM objects, even when the shapefile contains only XY geometries, and geometry.getDimension() returns 2.
The result of performing an operation such as an intersection between a geometry containing CoordinateXYZM objects and another geometry containing Coordinate objects, is potentially a geometry containing mixed Coordinate and CoordinateXYZM objects.
Performing a 2D transform operation on a geometry containing either Coordinate or CoordinateXYZM objects works fine, but performing the operation on one of these geometries containing mixed class Coordinate objects results in the "Invalid ordinate index: 3" exception.

The solution seems to be to ensure I get geometries from the shapefile containing only Coordinate objects instead of CoordinateXYZM objects.
There doesn't appear to be a way to configure that, so I need to just convert them afterwards.
Is that correct?
Or is there something I'm missing?
What is the most efficient way to convert them?
It seems there are no publicly accessible arrays in the Polygon classes that would allow me to simply drop in converted Coordinate objects, so I have to create each new Polygon or MultiPolygon from scratch but iterating through all the components.
Is that correct?
Efficiency is important for this application so if there is a way to solve the issue by configuring GeoTools that would be ideal.

By the shapefile specification a shapefile with a shape type=5 "polygon" cannot contain features with Z or M coordinates. By your description GeoTools does not check the shape type properly.

@user30184 Esri supports creating shapefiles with Z and M coordinates https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/creating-a-new-shapefile.htm and GeoTools was recently updated to read them https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/2779

The wikipedia article on the shapefile specification says it supports 3 or 4 dimensional coordinates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

I was reading the shapefile specification https://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/ao_/shapefile.pdf. Shape type 15 is PolygonZ that supports Z and M. If the shape type is 5 and the shapefile is valid then applications can trust that there are only X and Y. But it seems that PolygonZ and PolygonM are correctly checked in the code https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/2779/commits/9ca3e2b7e30a80e7320d180d16beb2c2b06d1905.

We would need to see your code and example shapefiles that exhibit the behaviour. Ideally, you should generate a small self contained test that demonstrates the issue and attach that to a ticket in jira

I discovered the problematic shapefiles did indeed contain some XYZ geometries. Strangely, these geometries still reported getDimension()==2.
I didn't find any existing tool to convert these geometries to contain CoordinateXY objects instead of CoordinateXYZM objects, so I used the following code:
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.CoordinateXY;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.LinearRing;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiLineString;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiPoint;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiPolygon;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon;

/**
 * Converts a <code><a target="_blank" href="https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html">Geometry</a></code>
 * containing <a target="_blank" href="https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Coordinate.html">coordinates</a>
 * with more than 2 dimensions, such as
 * <code><a target="_blank" href="https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/CoordinateXYZM.html">CoordinateXYZM</a></code>,
 * to a geometry containing <code><a target="_blank" href="https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/CoordinateXY.html">CoordinateXY</a></code>
 * coordinates.
 * <p>
 * This is necessary to avoid <code>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ordinate index: 3</code> exceptions when performing a transform on geometries with
 * mixed coordinate subclasses, which can result from performing an operation such as an intersection between geometries containing two different coordinate subclasses.
 * <p>
 * Since GeoTools 31.1, reading geometries from shapefiles sometimes results in geometries containing
 * <code><a target="_blank" href="https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/CoordinateXYZM.html">CoordinateXYZM</a></code> objects.
 * <p>
 * Therefore, to avoid issues, it's best to call {@link #convertToCoordinateXY(Geometry)} on every geometry read from a shapefile.
 */
public class CoordinateClassConversion {

    public static Geometry convertToCoordinateXY(Geometry geometry) {
        if (geometry==null || geometry.isEmpty()) return geometry;
        final Class<? extends Coordinate> coordinateClass=geometry.getCoordinate().getClass();
        if (coordinateClass==CoordinateXY.class) return geometry;
        if (coordinateClass==Coordinate.class) return geometry; // Base Coordinate class also doesn't seem to cause issues
        if (geometry instanceof Point) {
            return GeometryUtil.geometryFactory.createPoint(new CoordinateXY(geometry.getCoordinate()));
        } else if (geometry instanceof MultiPoint) {
            return GeometryUtil.geometryFactory.createMultiPointFromCoords(convertToCoordinateXY(geometry.getCoordinates()));
        } else if (geometry instanceof LinearRing) {
            return convertLinearRingToCoordinateXY((LinearRing)geometry);
        } else if (geometry instanceof LineString) {
            return convertLineStringToCoordinateXY((LineString)geometry);
        } else if (geometry instanceof MultiLineString) {
            return convertMultiLineStringToCoordinateXY((MultiLineString)geometry);
        } else if (geometry instanceof Polygon) {
            return convertPolygonToCoordinateXY((Polygon)geometry);
        } else if (geometry instanceof MultiPolygon) {
            return convertMultiPolygonToCoordinateXY((MultiPolygon)geometry);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected geometry type "+geometry.getClass());
        }
    }

    private static Coordinate[] convertToCoordinateXY(final Coordinate[] coordinates) {
        for (int i=0; i<coordinates.length; i++) coordinates[i]=new CoordinateXY(coordinates[i]);
        return coordinates;
    }

    private static LinearRing convertLinearRingToCoordinateXY(LinearRing linearRing) {
        return GeometryUtil.geometryFactory.createLinearRing(convertToCoordinateXY(linearRing.getCoordinates()));
    }

    private static LineString convertLineStringToCoordinateXY(LineString lineString) {
        return GeometryUtil.geometryFactory.createLineString(convertToCoordinateXY(lineString.getCoordinates()));
    }

    private static Polygon convertPolygonToCoordinateXY(Polygon polygon) {
        final LinearRing[] interiorRings=new LinearRing[polygon.getNumInteriorRing()];
        for (int i=0; i<interiorRings.length; i++) interiorRings[i]=convertLinearRingToCoordinateXY(polygon.getInteriorRingN(i));
        final LinearRing exteriorRing=convertLinearRingToCoordinateXY(polygon.getExteriorRing());
        return GeometryUtil.geometryFactory.createPolygon(exteriorRing,interiorRings);
    }

    private static MultiPolygon convertMultiPolygonToCoordinateXY(MultiPolygon multiPolygon) {
        final Polygon[] polygons=new Polygon[multiPolygon.getNumGeometries()];
        for (int i=0; i<polygons.length; i++) polygons[i]=convertPolygonToCoordinateXY((Polygon)multiPolygon.getGeometryN(i));
        return GeometryUtil.geometryFactory.createMultiPolygon(polygons);
    }

    private static MultiLineString convertMultiLineStringToCoordinateXY(MultiLineString multiLineString) {
        final LineString[] lineStrings=new LineString[multiLineString.getNumGeometries()];
        for (int i=0; i<lineStrings.length; i++) lineStrings[i]=convertLineStringToCoordinateXY((LineString)multiLineString.getGeometryN(i));
        return GeometryUtil.geometryFactory.createMultiLineString(lineStrings);
    }
}

